# C# app that does not access sql server db when run with windows task scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, task, scheduler, .net

I work on an application coded in c# (.net framework 4) and that accesses a database and reads/writes some tables.

When I run the app on the development machine it runs ok (tables are well written).
When I run the app on windows server 2003 outside task scheduler, it runs ok (tables are well written).
When I run the app on from windows task scheduler, it does not run ok (tables are not written at all).

I tried many accounts, and event the administrator one, to launch the task in task scheduler, but any account does not work.

I must write that an older version of the application runs ok on development machine, on windows server 2003 with/without windows task scheduler (tables are well written).

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Think we need to see the code that configures the database connection string.

Comment: How did you configure the task in scheduler?

Comment: The code is really basic for the connection to the database : SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("..."); The task is scheduled simply with an account in task scheduler (any account does not work). What is bizarre is that the old version of the app works correctly under task scheduler, but the new version does not. No added code around connections was added or removed or modified. I think that this may be a task scheduler problem but nothing is logged in event loggers...

Comment: You can try setting the startup directory for the scheduled task. If its not set, it defaults to system32. Perhaps it needs a local file that it can't find?

Comment: With the same account on windows server 2003 task scheduler, it works when run outside task scheduler but does not when run with task scheduler (with same account).

Comment: I'll try setting up the startup directory for the scheduled task, as suggested by akatakritos. I'll be able to do that in 5 days, and will let you know how it is. Until then, any other suggestion is welcome :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found that i had "integrated security" set to true in my connection string. This was forcing the task user to login to sql vs the connection string. I set this to false and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would recommend is to add lines:

```
Debugger.Break();
Debugger.Launch();
```

right where actual connection has to be opened and debug the application.
With this amount of information there's nothing else to advise.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the tip about "Debugger.Break()..." but can I debug the application when : 1) it is run on a remote windows server 2003 under windows task scheduler ? 2) I work on another computer with VS.NET 2010 Premium? Thanks

Comment: Use remote debugger. It works for managed code. You can find steps to configure it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx